# ios directory structure - space in directory name

Tags: ios

Please can someone explain how I can access the "Application Support" directory in my ios app's file structure. It seems necessary to use URLs, but the space character is causing the path to be interpreted as nil. I have tried various ways (escape, %20, etc) to no avail. Very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> explain how I can access the "Application Support" directory in my ios app's file structure

Like this (wrap this code in a do/catch construct):

```
let fm = FileManager.default  
let suppurl = try fm.url(for:.applicationSupportDirectory,       
    in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

Now `suppurl` is the URL of the Application Support directory.

Comment: Thanks very much Matt - extremely helpful :-)